# How can I activate a 2nd hand iPhone 3gs without a computer?

Tags: iphone

I have bought iPhone 3GS. But have not got a computer. How do I activate my phone?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for activation, using *any* computer with iTunes installed will do.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's possible. My advice is that you either buy a computer or build it yourself (this way is cheaper).

Comment: ...but he still has to buy the components right? This is not a an answer, this is bad advice.

Comment: @CousinCocaine It might not be an answer but it's a solution. With what did you contribute, skippy?